# How do I check if the current user is an admin for a Realm SyncUser?

Tags: swift, realm

I was expecting something like `SyncUser.current!.isAdmin` to access a boolean value, but currently as of version 2.5.0 there is not one. I've been perusing the docs and haven't been able to find anything regarding this, such as if client side we even have access to this variable.

Comment: The pull request was merged 4 days ago (but I'm a bit late with finding that) https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/4699

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect timing! [We JUST added that feature 4 days ago](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/4699). :)

Version 2.5.0 was shipped a week ago, so it won't be in any of the current release bundles until the next version ships. In the meantime, you can just pull the `master` branch of the Realm Cocoa repo (through CocoaPods or manually) and build it yourself to get that functionality right now.